# Programa para saber el salario de una persona que trabaja horas extras

Tags: java

El codigo para saber el salario de una persona que le pagan horas extras, despues de la hora 40 se paga así: ((pagoxhora*horastrabajadas)+pagoxhora/2+pagoxhora) osea que al empleado despues de la hora 41 le pagan como hora normal mas la mitad de una hora normal, no funciona no se cual sea el problema este es el codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class horasextras {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    long horasTrabajadas;
    long pagoxhora;
    long salario;

    System.out.print("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: ");
    horasTrabajadas=entrada.nextLong();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el pago por horas: ");
    pagoxhora=entrada.nextLong();
    
    if(horasTrabajadas<=40){
    pagoxhora=pagoxhora;
    }
    else{
    pagoxhora= (pagoxhora/2)+pagoxhora;
    }
    salario= horasTrabajadas*pagoxhora;
    System.out.println("El salario es de: "+salario);
}

}
```

Esto me refleja en la consola:

> Ingrese las horas trabajadas: 41
>
> Ingrese el pago por horas: 10
>
> El salario es de: 425

**tendria que ser: 415**

[image: este es el codigo y el resultado]

Comment: podrias poner cual es el error que te sale?

Comment: dos cosas.. es java o c++?? no puede ser las dos cosas.. y segundo.. en tu if, dice que si trabaja menos de 40 horas haga una cosa y si trabaja mas de 40 otra.. y en la explicacion dijiste otra cosa.. y si nos ponemos de acuerdo en lo que queres????

Comment: Es correcta la respuesta que dices que es incorrecta: horas trabajadas = 41, pago por horas = 10, horas trabajadas es mayor a 40 por lo tanto entra en el else y realiza la operación (10/2)+10 = 5+10 = 15, salario = 41*15 = 615. ¿De donde sacas que es 415?

Comment: @gbianchi quiero que me muestre que si las horas trabajdas son menos o igual que 40 el salario normal que serian horastrabajdas*pago_por_hora, pero si las horas trabajadas son mayores a 40 que el pago sea de: el pago normal + una hora trabajada + la mitad de una hora trab

Comment: yo creo que no tienes clara la logica de negocio. Probablemente si la persona trabaja 41 horas, se le pague 40 horas a un salario base y se le pague la 1 hora restante a un salario aumentado (150%?).

Comment: No edites tu pregunta para agregar una solucion. Si encontraste una solucion, ponla como respuesta.

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa ya leí las reglas, acabo de ponerlo como Stackoverflow manda

Comment: Los títulos no deben incluir etiquetas ni de lenguajes ni de estados (editado, solucionado). Ref. [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La formula que propones en la pregunta no coincide con la explicación que haces después, por eso te da el resultado que no es. Este código da el resultado que buscas.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    long horasTrabajadas;
    long pagoxhora;
    long salario;

    System.out.print("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: ");
    horasTrabajadas=entrada.nextLong();

    System.out.print("Ingrese el pago por horas: ");
    pagoxhora=entrada.nextLong();

    if(horasTrabajadas > 40){
        //calcula el salario de las primeras 40 horas
        long primerasHoras = 40 * pagoxhora;
        long precioHorasExtra = (pagoxhora/2)+pagoxhora;
        //calcula el salario de las horas extra
        long salarioHorasExtra = (horasTrabajadas - 40) * precioHorasExtra;

        salario = primerasHoras + salarioHorasExtra;//suma las dos cantidades
    }
    else{
        //menos de 40 horas trabajadas
        salario = pagoxhora * horasTrabajadas;
    }

    System.out.println("El salario es: " + salario);
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero agregar una explicación de ests código, tu repuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad. Revisar [answer]

Answer (score 1):

Revisemos tu codigo:

```
pagoxhora=entrada.nextLong(); //pedimos el pago por hora
if(horasTrabajadas<=40) // si las horas son menores a 40
    {pagoxhora=pagoxhora;} //hacemos que pagoxhora sea igual a pago por hora??? 
                           // para que??
else 
    {pagoxhora= (pagoxhora/2)+pagoxhora;} //o sea, si trabajo mas de 40 que cosa? 
                                          //no era el resto de lo que sobro de 40?
salario= horasTrabajadas*pagoxhora; //aca calculas el salario, cuan cualquier pago por hora.
```

Ahora.. primero ordenemos el algoritmo.
Queremos el pago por hora, y en realidad hay 2 pagos por hora.. uno para menos de 40, y otro para cada hora que supere las 40... entonces... en pseudocodigo seria algo asi:

- Pedimos el pago por hora
- calculamos el pago por hora extra (pago por hora * 1.5)
- Calculamos las horas trabajadas por encima de 40
- Calculamos el salario haciendo horas trabajadas hasta 40 * pago por hora + horas trabajadas por encima de 40 * pago por hora extra

y en codigo.. seria algo asi:

```
long pagoxhoraextra = 0;
int cantidadhorasextra = 0;
....
pagoxhora=entrada.nextLong();
pagoxhoraextra = (pagoxhora/2)+pagoxhora; // es lo mismo que pagoxhora * 1.5
if(horasTrabajadas>40)
{
    cantidadhorasextra = horasTrabajadas-40;
}
salario= (horasTrabajadas-cantidadhorasextra)*pagoxhora+cantidadhorasextra *pagoxhoraextra ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Soy nuevo en Java y estoy aprendiendo a programar de este modo, ojala te sirva este código. Saludos.

```
package horasextra;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //libreria para usar mensajes de Dialogos
public class HorasExtra {
    private void ingresarDatos(){//metodo para pedir los datos
        long horasTrabajadas;
        long pagoPorHora,total;
        horasTrabajadas=Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantas horas trabajo: "));//Pedimos las horas trabajadas por medio de un cuadro de dialogo.
        pagoPorHora=Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pago por Hora Trabajada: ")); //Pedimos el pago por medio de un cuadro de dialogo.
        total=calcularTotal(horasTrabajadas,pagoPorHora);//enviamos los datos al metodo calcularTotal() para realizar las operaciones
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"EL pago es de: "+total);
    }
    private long calcularTotal(long horasTra,long pagoHora){
    /*En este nuevo metodo resiviremos las horas trabajas y el pago por Hora y las definimos como horasTra y pagoHora para poder realizar las operaciones necesarias. */

        long pagoParcial,extra,pagoCompleto;
        if(horasTra>40){//si es mayor a 40
            pagoParcial=(40*pagoHora);//pago por las primeras 40 horas
            extra=(pagoHora+(pagoHora/2))*(horasTra-40); // pago por horas extras
            pagoCompleto=pagoParcial+extra;//sumas los dos pagos
            }
        else{
            pagoCompleto=horasTra*pagoHora; //sueldo por 40 o menos horas trabajadas.
        }
            return (pagoCompleto);   //retornamos pagoCompleto y se guarda en la variable total del metodo ingresarDatos().
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HorasExtra obj = new HorasExtra();//Creamos un objetos llamado obj para poder ingresar a los metodos de esta clase.
        obj.ingresarDatos();//ingresamos al metodo principal para obtener el resultado
    }

}
```

Comment: Podrias editar la respuesta explicar mas tu solución para que sea aceptada la respuesta

Comment: Listo, soy nuevo en la pagina, intento explicar lo mas que puedo. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para no cambiar mucho tu código ahí te envío una posible solución. Básicamente el error está en que computas todo el salario a 1.5 en vez de solo lo que te excedes de las 40hs. Saludos.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class horasextras {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
        long horasTrabajadas;
        long pagoxhora;
        long salario;
    System.out.print("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: ");
    horasTrabajadas=entrada.nextLong();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el pago por horas: ");
    pagoxhora=entrada.nextLong();

    if(horasTrabajadas<=40){
    salario= horasTrabajadas*pagoxhora;//salario normal
    }
    else{
    salario= (horasTrabajadas-40)*pagoxhora*1.5 + 40*pagoxhora;
    //este salario refleja el pago normal x 40hs + las horas extras que pagan    
    //1,5 veces
    }
    System.out.println("El salario es de: "+salario);
}

}
```